# Set factor values for multiple columns to missing without losing the label attribute

Tags: r, dplyr, attributes, r-factor, across

I have surveydata with a number of likert-scale items that have been imported as factors where the actual question is attached to those factors as the "label" attribute.
In addition, there is one random variable that has been assigned to each participant and was used for different routings of the questionnaire.
For example if the random number is 1 or 2, the questionnaire would display a certain group of items (e.g G1, G2, G3, etc.). If the random number was 3, those items would be skipped, hence their values should be missing.

In some cases due to technical issues, groups of items were still displayed and answered even if they shouldn't have been displayed. I would like to set them missing programmatically for the whole group of items, depending on the random variable, using across() and case_when.

However, I have some trouble keeping the label attribute when trying to set the values to NA.
Here are some fabricated test data to illustrate the problem:

```
set.seed(123)
test_df <-
  tibble(
    random_number = rep(1:3, each = 2),  
    G1  = factor(sample(c("Never", "Sometimes", "Often"), size = 6, replace = TRUE), levels = c("Never", "Sometimes", "Often")),
    G2  = factor(sample(c("Never", "Sometimes", "Often"), size = 6, replace = TRUE), levels = c("Never", "Sometimes", "Often")),
    G3  = factor(sample(c("Never", "Sometimes", "Often"), size = 6, replace = TRUE), levels = c("Never", "Sometimes", "Often")),
    G4  = factor(sample(c("Never", "Sometimes", "Often"), size = 6, replace = TRUE), levels = c("Never", "Sometimes", "Often")))

attributes(test_df$G1)$label <- "Question 1: Do you use R?"
attributes(test_df$G2)$label <- "Question 2: Do you use Python?"
attributes(test_df$G3)$label <- "Question 3: Do you use SQL?"
attributes(test_df$G4)$label <- "Question 4: Do you use PowerBI?"
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

attributes(test_df$G1)
$levels
[1] "Never"     "Sometimes" "Often"    

$class
[1] "factor"

$label
[1] "Question 1: Do you use R?" #label still here.
```

All items starting with G should be missing if the random number is 3

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  random_number G1    G2        G3        G4       
          <int> <fct> <fct>     <fct>     <fct>    
1             1 Often Often     Often     Often    
2             1 Often Sometimes Sometimes Sometimes
3             2 Never Often     Never     Never    
4             2 Never Sometimes Often     Often    
5             3 Never Never     Often     Never    #should be missing
6             3 Never Sometimes Never     Never    #should be missing
```

The code below works for setting the correct values missing but due to the conversion to character and back to factor, the label attribute gets dropped.

```
test_df_no_label <-
test_df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(.cols = dplyr::matches("[G]\\d{1,2}"),
                              .fns  = ~dplyr::case_when(random_number != 3 ~ as.character(.x),
                                                        TRUE ~ NA_character_) %>%
                                factor(levels = c("Never", "Sometimes", "Often"))))

> test_df_no_label
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  random_number G1    G2        G3        G4       
          <int> <fct> <fct>     <fct>     <fct>    
1             1 Often Often     Often     Often    
2             1 Often Sometimes Sometimes Sometimes
3             2 Never Often     Never     Never    
4             2 Never Sometimes Often     Often    
5             3 NA    NA        NA        NA       #are now missing, good
6             3 NA    NA        NA        NA  
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
# label attribute is gone

> attributes(test_df_no_label$G1)
$levels
[1] "Never"     "Sometimes" "Often"    

$class
[1] "factor"
```

I've also tried .fns  = ~ifelse(random_number != 3, .x, NA_character_) but that converted the factor to numeric. Any ideas about how to avoid dropping the label when setting the values to missing? The real df has many more items and many more groups, so I would like to avoid hard-coding it manually.

Answer (score 0):

As Hadley notes in [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html#getting-and-setting):

> Attributes should generally be thought of as ephemeral. For example, most attributes are lost by most operations.

But one option to keep your labels would be to make use of a helper function which first saves the `label` attribute and resets is afterwards:

```r
library(dplyr)

to_na <- function(x, rn) {
  label <- attr(x, "label")
  levels <- levels(x)
  
  x <- as.character(x)
  x[rn == 3] <- NA_character_
  x <- factor(x, levels = levels)
  attr(x, "label") <- label
  
  x
}

test_df <- test_df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(
    .cols = dplyr::matches("[G]\\d{1,2}"),
    .fns = ~ to_na(.x, random_number)))

test_df
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>   random_number G1        G2        G3        G4   
#>           <int> <fct>     <fct>     <fct>     <fct>
#> 1             1 Often     Sometimes Never     Never
#> 2             1 Often     Sometimes Sometimes Never
#> 3             2 Often     Often     Often     Never
#> 4             2 Sometimes Never     Never     Never
#> 5             3 <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA> 
#> 6             3 <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>

lapply(test_df, attr, "label")
#> $random_number
#> NULL
#> 
#> $G1
#> [1] "Question 1: Do you use R?"
#> 
#> $G2
#> [1] "Question 2: Do you use Python?"
#> 
#> $G3
#> [1] "Question 3: Do you use SQL?"
#> 
#> $G4
#> [1] "Question 4: Do you use PowerBI?"
```